# Bug? ByteString function returning quotation mark upon calling it

Tags: haskell

Ive got two two functions which act on byte strings. The first one is a bytestring version of the cycle function in Data.List and the second function rotates the bytestring.

When I read a file and send its input to the rotateBytes function, it outputs a quotation mark and then I need to press Control-C to manually stop the function. Is this a bug in my code or a bug in ghc? How can it be fixed?

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

-- Cycle function for binary data
cycleBytes :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString 
cycleBytes xs 
    | B.null xs = error "cycleBytes: empty list"
    | otherwise = xs' where xs' = xs `B.append` xs'

-- Rotate function for binary data
rotateBytes :: B.ByteString -> Int -> B.ByteString
rotateBytes xs n = B.take (B.length xs) $! B.drop (B.length xs + n) $! cycleBytes xs
```

Using the function is currently like this:

```
*Main> B.readFile "test.dat" >>= (\x -> return $ rotateBytes x 3)
"
^CInterrupted.
```

Comment: Haskell's laziness means that the open quote will be printed before the ByteString's contents are even computed, so that's where the lone quote's coming from. Most likely you've got an infinite loop in rotateBytes, so it never gets a chance to print anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ByteString isn't lazy so can't cope with the infinite answer from `cycleBytes`. (The `"` you're getting is because when printing the result, it can lazily get the first character of output without worrying about the rest, but then tries to calculate the infinite ByteString it gets from `cycleBytes` before printing anything else. Infinity and strict evaluation don't mix.)

1. Import `Data.ByteString.Lazy` instead (and use `fromIntegral` on your `n`, because it wants `Int64` not `Int`; You might want to use Lazy ByteStrings for enormous amounts of data, so you the library needs a length parameter that allows this.)
2. or (better) reduce `n` mod `B.length xs` and just use  `B.append xs xs` instead of infinitely many.

Solution 1 looks like

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

-- Cycle function for binary data
cycleBytes :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString 
cycleBytes xs 
    | B.null xs = error "cycleBytes: empty list"
    | otherwise = xs' where xs' = xs `B.append` xs'


-- Rotate function for binary data
rotateBytes :: B.ByteString -> Int -> B.ByteString
rotateBytes xs n = B.take (B.length xs) 
                 $ B.drop (B.length xs + fromIntegral n) 
                 $ cycleBytes xs
```

If `test.dat` contained `Hello Mum!` this would calculate `Chunk "lo Mum!" (Chunk "Hel" Empty)`, because it's lazily constructed and will only get combined if it's forced.

Solution 2 looks like

```
rotateBytes :: B.ByteString -> Int -> B.ByteString
rotateBytes xs n = 
    let len = B.length xs
        n' = n `mod` len in
     B.take len $! B.drop n' $! B.append xs xs
```

Solution 2 is better partly because you get to keep everything strict (which I assume you were trying to do), but doesn't have `cycleBytes`.

Ben Millwood suggests replacing this with something along the lines of

```
rotateBytes :: B.ByteString -> Int -> B.ByteString
rotateBytes xs n = 
    let n' = n `mod` B.length xs 
        (beginning,end) = B.splitAt n' xs in
    B.append end beginning
```

which reads more clearly. `take`, `drop` and `splitAt` are all *O(1)* in `ByteString`, so it doesn't make much difference for efficiency, but the `splitAt` does feel cleaner.

Comment: That second answer is perfect for what I am doing. Thanks!

Comment: "because for some reason it wants `Int64` not `Int`" <- Even on a 32 bit system, people may want to work with lazy `Bytetring`s longer than 2GB, so you can't use `Int` for the length and associated functions.

Comment: Instead of the `B.append xs xs` thing I'd just use `splitAt`, swap the pieces, and rejoin. Not that it matters much.

Comment: @BenMillwood I completely agree: It's preferable, even if it doesn't make a lot of difference. Thanks.

Comment: @BenMillwood sorry about that thoughtless typo. Thanks for fixing.